# Auto-populate values based on multiple dependencies in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have three columns with information filled in already. The value in Column C is dependent on two identifiers from Columns A & B (i.e., George is always the seller of Apples in America, but Sarah is the seller of Beets).

I have enough data in rows 1-8 that I want the cells from 9 onwards to start automatically filling the required information each time I input a new row.

Thus, if I enter in "Beets" in A9 and "Australia" in B9, then C9 should pull the value "Amy". I will pull this value down to autofill the rest of the table for future rows to be added automatically filling.

I used the INDIRECT(ROW-1) function to reference the whole column above the cell with the formula to get the correct data, if that makes sense...

```
       A         B         C
1   Product  Country    Contact 
2   Apple    Australia  John
3   Apple    America    George
4   Beets    Australia  Amy
5   Beets    America    Sarah
6   Carrot   Australia  Greg
7   Carrot   America    Belinda
8   Apple    Australia  John 
9   Beets    Australia  _Formula:_

=INDEX((INDIRECT("C2:C"&ROW()-1)),MATCH(A10,IF((INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW()-1))=B10,(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1)))),0)
```

Comment: Does your existing data account for all possible values for C, or could you encounter a combination where you would need to enter a new value for C?

Comment: Hi Fixer, yeah sorry multiple edits occuring at once, I realised that I didn't have the range defined correctly in my example, but the fix is still returning #N/A. It doesn't need to have any error handling, any new country/product combination can be manually entered in. The Indirect Function hopefully adds this new value to the next time this occurrence happens.

P.S. I'm also trying the formula as an Array

Comment: A much simpler approach: create a lookup table with two columns--A&B and C for the seven combinations.  For each new row, lookup A&B.

Comment: Hi Fixer, Appreciate your response and solution, though I'd rather figure out why my formula isn't working... Also, the example is a more simplified solution. I have multiple Products (4+) possible products per country (10+) making the combinations endless for a lookup table.

Comment: @Stacker: BTW, if you "address" your comment like this, the person will get a message flag, otherwise, nobody will be aware of your posting (needed if more than one person is associated with a question or answer).  Suggestion: add a helper column with A&B (can be hidden).  Then just do index/match on the rows above the current row.

Comment: @Stacker: BTW, there's no good reason for row 8 to be a pure data row, is there?  `Apple` / `Australia` / `John` is a repeat of row 2, and so `C8` = `John` could be done by formula, too; right?

Comment: @stacker Why do you want to create **duplicate rows**?

Comment: @DavidPostill Order entry. each row also has a unique ID and other varying info (like number of apples)

Comment: @Stacker: We encourage people to streamline their Qs & As, omitting irrelevant information, and you did a pretty good job of that.  But I was also wondering what David asked (Why do you want to create duplicate rows?), and it would have helped us understand the question if you have stated from the outset that there are other column(s), and this exercise is intended to fill in a redundant (derivable) value in a larger row.  (It might also have been clearer if rows 2-7 were separated from the rest of the data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer that seems to work:

```
=VLOOKUP(B9, OFFSET(B$2:C$7, MATCH(A9,A$2:A$7,0)-1, 0, 2, 2), 2, 0)
```

Working from the inside out:

- `VLOOKUP(B9, OFFSET(B$2:C$7, MATCH(A9,A$2:A$7,0) -1, 0, 2, 2), 2, 0)`
  `MATCH(A9, A$2:A$7, 0)` finds `A9` (`Beets`) in the range `A2:A7`
  { `Apple`, `Apple`, `Beets`, `Beets`, `Carrot`, `Carrot` },
  yielding an index value in the range 1-6. 
  Of course, because `A2` = `A3`, `A4` = `A5`, and `A6` = `A7`,
  the index value will always be 1, 3, or 5; for `Beets`, it is 3.
- `MATCH(A9, A$2:A$7, 0)-1` remaps the above to be in the range 0-5 (specifically, 0, 2, or 4; for `Beets`, it is 2).
- `OFFSET(B$2:C$7, the_above, 0, 2, 2)` says

  - take the `B2:C7` region,
  - from the top left corner (`B2`), go down two rows
    (since the first occurrence of `Beets` in `A2:A7` is in the third row,
    that means we must go down two (3−1) rows from row 2) and go right zero columns,
    arriving at cell `B4`,
  - and then take a 2×2 region starting from that point.
    which gets us to the range `B4:C5`, which is

    ```
    Australia   Amy
    America     Sarah
    ```

    which is the world-wide list of beets sellers. 
    Note that we want a region that’s two columns wide,
    because we want to associate countries with sellers,
    but the height should be the number of countries
    (which happens to be two in this example). 
    If there were seven countries, we would change this to
    `OFFSET(B$2:C$7, MATCH(A9,A$2:A$7,0)-1, 0, 7, 2)`
    (Although, if there were seven countries (and three commodities),
    the introductory block would be 21 rows high,
    so we’d be using ranges from row 2 to row 22.)
- `VLOOKUP(B9, OFFSET(B$2:C$7, MATCH(A9,A$2:A$7,0)-1, 0, 2, 2) , 2, 0)`
  `VLOOKUP` (and its brothers, `LOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP`) are, essentially,
  shorthand for `INDEX`+`MATCH`. 
  This searches the first column (the `V` stands for **v**ertical)
  of the beets sellers region/array (`B4:C5`) for `B9` (`Australia`)
  and then returns the value from the 2nd column
  of the row that matched the lookup value (`Australia`). 
  `Australia` is in row 4. 
  Since we are talking about Columns `B` and `C`,
  Column `C` is “the 2nd column” in this context,
  so this gets us to cell `C4`, which contains `Amy`.

… which is the desired result for row 9,
since Amy is the Australian beet vendor.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help and also explanation. Works really well I cannot thank you enough :)

Comment: My pleasure.  I apologize for taking so long to post the explanation.